# C# How can I make a loop for finding spaces in a sentence?

Tags: c#, string, loops, data-manipulation

a task I have in my college work is to:

> Create an application that will accept into a text box any number of words each separated from the next by a single space. When a “Show Words” button is clicked each of the individual words entered are to be displayed on a separate line in a list box. (Hint: use a loop to repeatedly find a space, copy the word before the space to the list box and then remove the word and space from the string – stop when there are no more spaces in the string)

In previous questions similar to this I have used a loop for a specific amount of words in the sentence but I have no idea how to make a loop for finding the spaces in a sentence with unlimited length, I don't think I can use an array because it's unlimited also.
any help with this is much appreciated

Comment: [so] is to *help* with programming problems, not to do them for you.

Comment: So what have you got already? We are happy to help you, but please show some effort. The point of such assignment is for you to learn something, not to copy someone else's code.

Comment: Define a loop, find the first space, copy the word before the space, cut word with space, next... ezpz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Homework questions are okay here. It is not a valid close reason.

Comment: You original text does have a limit, you just don't know it. Start with the `originalText.Length` to know about it.

Your loop can be done by using a `for` (using that `.Length` property) or a `foreach` (and here you don't need to know the size in advance)

For each character in the original text (which you can extract by using a `.Substring` method), check if it's a space; if isn't a space, add that char into a current word variable; if is a space (and you current word variable isn't empty), display the current word variable and reset it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." this question is not about problem. It is about: solve my homework for me, i don't want to think.

Comment: So voting to close because it is homework it is wrong. It is okay to close it because it is missing a MVCE. @KirillBestemyanov

Comment: @PatrickHofman i can vote to close by any reason that i thought valid. You can vote for reopen if you want.

Comment: No, you can't. It should be closed as it is, but your close reason is just wrong. @KirillBestemyanov

Comment: @PatrickHofman i am not agreed with you about close reasons, and already pass argumentation about this with reference to help center. If this question fitted the rule there would be no information about homework at all and there were normal description about problem. The words "homework", "collegework" etc is usually a marker of bad question with no thoughts above.

Comment: I'm sorry guys for how I asked the question, but no need to get all serious about it, I'm new to stackoverflow and I didn't upload code because I didn't have any after deleting the code over 5 times or so and I just wanted a general direction not the exact code I needed but thank you to those who posted actual answers rather than rage I am close to making this work

Answer (score 1):

Just use `string.Split`,

```
"Some Words".Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

now, I don't know if you'll get marks if you don't directly use a loop. This will return the data

```
string[]
   {
       "Some",
       "Words"
   };
```

I'm not going to tell you how to use this with a ComboBox for two reasons, its not the central point of the question and, you don't say what technology you are using e.g. WPF, Winforms, ASP.Net etc. etc.

Comment: sorry for being very thin with this guys I would share code but I was just more or less stuck with what I should use whether it be an array etc I dont need you to do the work just steer me in the right direction, i have tried multiple times using arrays in different ways with no luck and other means but I'll give that a try as well thank you jodrell

Answer (score 1):

Use this code this will solve your problem.

```
int position = myString.IndexOf(' ');  // to find first space
int lastpos=0;
while (position >= 0)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the position.
    string sub = input.Substring(lastpos, position-1);  // here input is the text you get from input box
    lastpos = position+1;
    // to find next space in sentence
    position = myString.IndexOf(' ', position + 1);
}
```